# How to publish NPM package to NPM registry instead of github registry?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish, github-package-registry, npm-registry

I have created an NPM package like so - (https://github.com/fyndreact/nitrozen)

I'm able to successfully publish the package on github (https://npm.pkg.github.com/)
However, what I want to do is publish it on NPM registry.

I'm not able to see the package in the NPM registry https://www.npmjs.com/

Thing's I have already tried doing:

#### Login & publish NPM commands

1. `NPM login`
2. `NPM publish --access=public`

#### Removing the following publishConfig from package.json and publishing it.

```
   "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/fyndreact",
   "access": "public"
 }
```

After running the NPM publish command, I'm able to see this

```
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @fyndreact/nitrozen                     
npm notice version:       2.2.6                                   
npm notice filename:      @fyndreact/nitrozen-2.2.6.tgz           
npm notice package size:  223.2 kB                                
npm notice unpacked size: 3.0 MB                                  
npm notice shasum:        4eac8e8aea03c5d085a5814e536fd42c24f15c40
npm notice integrity:     sha512-/8cTfavmOVDd9[...]AY8b3mFWHkTOQ==
npm notice total files:   207                                     
npm notice 
npm notice Publishing to https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

How do I publish the package to NPM registry (https://www.npmjs.com/) instead of github registry (https://npm.pkg.github.com) ?
I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "@fyndreact/nitrozen",
  "version": "2.2.7",
  "description": "React component library inspired by Nitrozen",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup -c",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "npm test -- --coverage",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -o docs",
    "lint:check": "prettier --check .",
    "lint:format": "prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --fix",
    "*.{css,scss,sass}": "stylelint --fix",
    "**/*": "prettier -w -u"
  },
  "author": "Fynd Opex frontend",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.1.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^14.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.5.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.5.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "rollup": "^2.79.0",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-less": "^1.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.11",
    "babel-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.3",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-img": "^1.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "access": "public"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine but you need to change the below code in **publishConfig**

```
 "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "access": "public"
  },
```

Ref:https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/registry

Comment: Even after adding this in package.json, it is still publishing to https://npm.pkg.github.com/

Comment: can you share the me package.json file

Comment: If you see these lines @OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com remove that and remove the npm user  login again

Comment: I have edited the question & added the package.json now.  These lines @OWNER:registry=npm.pkg.github.com are not there anywhere in the project anymore

Comment: Did you check the .npmrc file?